# How SOCKS5 infers the destination port within SSH dynamic forwarding?

Tags: ssh, proxy, portforwarding, socks, tunneling

When using local forwarding we are free to pick destination port:

`ssh -L 8000:10.10.1.11:80 user@192.168.56.102` - **80 is destination port - we explicitly specify which port to forward to**.

Take a look at [diagram in this article](http://www.teqlog.com/access-blocked-computers-servers-ssh-tunneling-port-forwarding.html). If I understand correctly, in dynamic forwarding destination port is somewhat implicit (?):

`ssh -D 8080 user@192.168.56.102` - 8080 is local host port, but still it **somehow forwards to 80** for us.

Questions:

- How SOCKS5 proxy knows which port to forward traffic to?
- Does SOCKS5 proxy somehow sniff destination from the protocol of the traffic it proxies?
- Can that destination port be configured?
- Where is it configured - on my local machine, or remote that does final forwarding for us? Nowhere?
- Is it a predefined fixed set of protocols/ports? Smth like http=80 destination port?
- Any other internal details of forwarding you can add to clarify the picture.

thanks.

PS. Here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213213/difference-between-local-port-forwarding-and-dynamic-port-forwarding#comment401063_213219 i found some hint to what i'm interested in, pity there are no details provided...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH and SOCKS are two completely different and unrelated protocols.  But, to answer your questions:

> How SOCKS5 proxy knows which port to forward traffic to?

A SOCKS client explicitly tells it where to connect. The destination host/ip and port are input fields in the SOCKS `CONNECT` command. So, there is no guessing/infering at all.

> Does SOCKS5 proxy somehow sniff destination from the protocol of the traffic it proxies?

No. SOCKS is just a tunnel of raw bytes, it has no concept of protocols beyond its own.

> Can that destination port be configured?

Not on the proxy itself, no.  Since the client decides where to connect, any configuration would be on the client side.

> Is it a predefined fixed set of protocols/ports? Smth like http=80 destination port?

No.

> Any other internal details of forwarding you can add to clarify the picture.

Read the SOCKS protocol specs.

SOCKS v4: https://www.openssh.com/txt/socks4.protocol

SOCKS v4a: https://www.openssh.com/txt/socks4a.protocol

SOCKS v5: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1928

Comment: hi. yep, those are unrelated, i know it. i'm interested in its usage within SSH dynamic forwarding (see command line example in question itself). what remains unclear for me is why `ssh -D` above does not specify final destination port - i.e. 80. (i've also edited title, thanks for pointing)

Comment: here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213213/difference-between-local-port-forwarding-and-dynamic-port-forwarding#comment401063_213219 i found some hint to what i'm interested in. i'm lacking details there...

Comment: @Max OK, but that is not what you actually asked about. You mentioned SSH, but you asked about SOCKS instead. SSH and SOCKS have nothing to do with either other.

Comment: ok thanks. i see now that it is fair to say that target port will work like this: 1) i set forwarding `ssh -D 8080 ...` on my comp, 2) say, i install browser SOCKS5 extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-helper/mnloefcpaepkpmhaoipjkpikbnkmbnic) , and it is precisely that extension that seemlessly sets up forwarding to target machine's port 80 (`DST.PORT` in socks5 spec?) - remote machine's sshd picks that because socks5 proxy on client side provided that info. i just want to understand interplay of socks5 and ssh here...